# R for loop over multiple variable

Tags: r, for-loop

What's the idiomatic way in R to loop over 2 vectors like this in Python

```
for i,j in zip(Is, Js)
```

The obvious way in R is to go along the index

```
for (idx in seq_along(Is)) {
    i = Is[idx]
    j = Js[idx]
```

}

Just wonder if there is a less cumbersome way?

Edit:

I'm using for loop for parameter scan and then plotting. A preferred way to avoid for loop will be also helpful. So for example

```
results = data.table()
for (threshold in c(2,3,4,5)) {
    largeRtn = rtn[abs(rtn)>threshold*volatility]
    results = rbind(results, someAnalysis(largeRtn) )
    qplot(largeRtn, ...)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? Generally, for-loops in R are not the way to go. You could consider providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: avoid it when you can - most functions take vectors as input, there arent nice iterators like in python.

Comment: @Heroka, I added one example although still not a "working example".

Comment: Would you be able to answer this question given the data you've given?

Comment: @Heroka, sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: Your question is incomplete and you show very little effort in either making it clearer/reproducible or commenting why the given solutions are not what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your python code does, but maybe the `foreach` and `iterators` packages are an option:

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)

zip <- function(...) iter(obj = expand.grid(...), by = "row")
foreach(d = zip(i = 1:3, j = 5:10), .combine = c) %do% {d[,"i"] * d[,"j"]}
#[1]  5 10 15  6 12 18  7 14 21  8 16 24  9 18 27 10 20 30
```

Of course, you should avoid loops if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is typically R-like:

```
func = function(a, b) {
    return(a*b)
}
a = c(2,3,1,7,8)
b = c(4,6,7,0,1)
mapply(func, a = a, b = b)
[1]  8 18  7  0  8
```

Of course in this case, one can easily do this vectorized:

```
a * b
[1]  8 18  7  0  8
```

But in more complex cases, vectorization might not be an option, then you can use the first approach.

Maybe [this tutorial](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_control_flow.html) I wrote can help you out.